# Normative philosophy vs descriptive philosophy

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-science, epistemology, ontology, truth

I am making the question in simple terms to avoid logical ambiguity.

IS normative philosophy(what should be) a subset of descriptive philosophy (What is) ?

Is morality/ethics beauty/happiness is also truth.

Comment: What is "normative philosophy" ? And what "descriptive philosophy" would describe?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA there are very good literatures but u can start from https://youtu.be/mm8asJxdcds?t=84      starts from 1.21

Comment: Maybe the distinction can be relevant for ethics... but what about *ontology*? What is "normative ontology"? someone legislating about what king of entity must exist? And what about "truth"?

Comment: If "descriptive philosophy" means metaphysics (what is) and  "normative philosophy" means ethics (what should be) then the answer is controversial and depends on the status of moral values. [Moral realists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-realism/) say yes, they objectively exist and are part of metaphysics, [moral anti-realists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-anti-realism/) say otherwise.

Comment: Ethics, aesthetics and political philosophy might be considered normative, at least by some philosophers. Traditionally, logic is also considered to be normative, though that is a disputed issue today. Some accounts of epistemology consider knowledge to be the product of 'good' processes, which might suggest some normativity.

Comment: Your right concern is the famous "theory-ladenness" claim of most postmodernists thus you may know the answer by now...